# LINQ: What's the best way to await in where?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await, where-clause

The following code example works of course:

```
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var smallInts = ints.Where(i => i < 3);
```

But what if need to call an async method in a Where condition?

```
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var smallInts = ints.Where(async i => { return await IsSmallInt(i); });
```

This results in the following error:

> Error 21: Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type
>   'System.Func'. An async lambda expression may return
>   void, Task or Task, none of which are convertible to
>   'System.Func'.

Of course I could just write a foreach loop in this case, but I don't want to.

```
var smallInts = new List<int>();
foreach (int i in ints)
    if (await IsSmallInt(i))
        smallInts.Add(i);
```

So what's the best way (and maybe also the shortest way) to use await in a Where condition?

Comment: Why do you want to make it asynchronous? Is there some IO-bound computation in your **IsSmallInt** method? If not, asynchronous programming will not be of any help and you should stick with the synchronous version.

Comment: [LINQ has very limited support for async/await](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16624843/859154)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868087/how-to-await-a-list-of-tasks-asynchronously-using-linq 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252355/how-to-write-asynchronous-linq-query 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176722/how-to-write-async-linq 

Google: what a beautiful little thing ...

Comment: You can write your WhereAsync quite simple, sadly i can not post it anymore: Select a anonymous class containing a the Task<bool> predicate and the value. Await all. and selet the values again.