# How to await during Select in a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await

I am attempting to perform a Lambda Select using Entity Framework from a table into a new model but I need to be able to call an asynchronous method to populate a property on each instance in the return set:

```
await Task.WhenAll(_context.UserContacts.Where(uc => uc.UserId == user.Id).Select(async uc => new MailContact
            {
                Email = uc.Contact.Email,
                UserId = uc.Contact.UserId,
                ContactId = uc.Contact.Id,
                Name = uc.Contact.UserId != null ? await _graphService.GetUserByIdAsync(uc.Contact.UserId) : null;
            }
```

I understand that Linq has limited support for await/async and I've looked at several other examples on StackOverflow where the asynchronous part is moved into a seperate loop, eg:

[How to await a method in a Linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624648/how-to-await-a-method-in-a-linq-query)

```
T[] data = await Task.WhenAll(contacts.Select(c => LoadDataAsync(c)));
```

However, this method wont let me update the object referred to as "c" unless I pass by reference which isn't allowed on async methods.

Can someone explain the most efficient way to populate the name property correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a wrapper:

```
    private async Task<string> GetDisplayName(string userId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) return null;
        var contactUser = await _graphService.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);
        return contactUser.DisplayName;
    }
```

and changing the assignment to this:

```
    Name = u.UserId != null ? await GetDisplayName(u.UserId) : null
```

Answer (score 7):

You just have to do the secondary lookup in LINQ-to-Objects, not LINQ-to-Entities:

```
// LINQ-to-Entities
var users = await _context.UserContacts
    .Where(uc => uc.UserId == user.Id)
    .Select(uc => new
    {
      uc.Contact.Email,
      uc.Contact.UserId,
      ContactId = uc.Contact.Id,
    })
    .ToListAsync();

// LINQ-to-Objects
var lookupTasks = users.Select(async u => new
    {
      u.Email,
      u.UserId,
      u.ContactId,
      Name = u.UserId != null ? await _graphService.GetUserByIdAsync(u.UserId) : null;
    });
return await Task.WhenAll(lookupTasks);
```

The idea is you push as much logic into the initial LINQ-to-Entities query, including filtering and projection. Then you execute it (`ToListAsync`).

Then you take your DB results and do the secondary lookup.

Comment: I think you may have meant to use `return await Task.WhenAll(lookupTasks);` Not `return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: Right, got it.  It didnt occur to me to reselect all the properties into a new dynamic property as well :)

Comment: If i wanted to just return a property of the object i get back from GetUserByIdAsync how do i access it (.Result.DisplayName)?  I get warned there is no GetAwaiter definition?

Comment: @SteveWhitaker: You'd probably have to put parenthesis around `await`, like `(await GetUserByIdAsync(id)).DisplayName`.